# Mongodb aggregate sum embedded key pair objects

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection

```
{

  "pos": 1
  "daily": 1,
  "hourly": {
    "15": 1,
    "23": 4
  }
}
```

hourly ranges from 0 to 23, I just want to group by position and want to aggregate($sum) daily and individual hours. Hourly is bit tricking me.

Comment: Not really sure you are asking. Do you want to sum up all the values in "hourly" or do you want each "hourly" total from 0..23?

Comment: sum value for individual hours @Blakes

Comment: I thought you might say that. You have both possibilities now anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/mapReduce/) for this, the aggregation framework cannot traverse the keys of an object:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var obj = { "daily": this.daily, "hourly": {} };
        for ( var x=0; x <= 23; x++ ) {
            obj.hourly[x] = 0;
        }

        var hourly = this.hourly;
        Object.keys(hourly).forEach(function(hour) {
            obj.hourly[hour] += hourly[hour];
        });
        emit(null, obj);
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var obj = { "daily": 0, "hourly": {} };
        for ( var x=0; x <= 23; x++ ) {
            obj.hourly[x] = 0;
        }

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            obj.daily += value.daily;
            Object.keys(value.hourly).forEach(function(hour) {
                obj.hourly[hour] += value.hourly[hour];
            });
        });
        return obj;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Or if you mean you just want the total of "hourly" then do this:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var obj = { "daily": this.daily, "hourly": 0 };

        var hourly = this.hourly;
        hourly.forEach(function(hour) {
            obj.hourly+= hourly[hour];
        });
        emit(null, obj);
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var obj = { "daily": 0, "hourly": 0 };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            obj.daily += value.daily;
            obj.hourly += value.hourly;
        });
        return obj;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Doing this with the aggregation framework looks pretty horrible. Shourtening the hours here, but you should see what is basically required:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "daily": { "$sum": "$daily" },
        "0": { "$sum": "$hourly.0" },
        "1": { "$sum": "$hourly.1" }, 
        "2": { "$sum": "$hourly.2" },
        "3": { "$sum": "$hourly.3" },
        "4": { "$sum": "$hourly.4" },
        "5": { "$sum": "$hourly.5" },
        "6": { "$sum": "$hourly.6" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "daily": 1,
        "hourly": {
            "0": "$0",
            "1": "$1",
            "2": "$2",
            "3": "$3",
            "4": "$4",
            "5": "$5",
            "6": "$6"
        }
    }}
])
```

Or again to just total up the "hourly" values,

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "daily": { "$sum": "$daily" },
        "hourly": { 
            "$sum": { "$add": [
                "$hourly.0",,
                "$hourly.1",
                "$hourly.2",
                "$hourly.3",
                "$hourly.4",
                "$hourly.5",
                "$hourly.6"
            ]}
        }
    }}
])
```

You can of course use code to generate the aggregation pipeline stages since they are only data structures anyway. So a similar approach as shown in the mapReduce example ( looping 0..23 ) can be used to generate.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy . Btw, `emit(null, obj);`  this line should be `emit(pos, obj)` as I want to group by position

Comment: @Peramanathan The example I am giving in that case produces every single position summed in a singular result as opposed to a document per "postion". Which of course is another way to approach if that is what you want to achieve.